# What happens if every question is duplicate on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

There are approximately 5k question asked every day. Nowadays approximately 4 out of 10 questions I checked is a duplicate. This ratio will increase with time.

What happens if every question will be duplicate?

Comment: It won’t happen. The number of potential questions is unbounded, the number of questions already asked at any point in time is not only finite but small. And even if you don’t buy that: technology changes quickly, new frameworks are introduced, old ones get new versions, whole new disciplines open up, etc. It won’t happen.

Comment: New changes not frequently come as question.

Comment: Novel problems using existing tech do. By definition. But it doesn’t matter. I am not asking you, I am telling you: it won’t happen.

Comment: No, but when a new change arrives, often plenty of questions accompany that change to even out that frequency. I doubt we need to worry about this. (If worst comes to worst, we can all play duplicate-memory)

Comment: @Codeer you are right. That's why i'm asking this question.

Comment: If we can close all future questions as duplicates, I'd say SOs mission is accomplished.

Comment: I have the nagging feeling that we'll give up trying to close as a duplicate long before we even get close to that happening, so the site will just fill with duplicates and on meta we'll be having endless wars about what to do about it.

Comment: If you really see 4 out of 10 questions to be duplicate, I would appreciate if you flag these questions as such. That guides those who asked the question quickly to  useful answers.

Comment: Question for you: how is that a problem?

Comment: If 4 out of 10 question of an user are duplicate, How do I close the user ?

Comment: You're ___WAY___ overestimating the problem. I've ran [the numbers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/870309/how-high-is-the-fraction-of-posts-closed-as-duplicates), and about 3% of all questions posted from last SEDE week got closed as a duplicate, including the ones that got reopened, compared to [2%](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/870309/how-high-is-the-fraction-of-posts-closed-as-duplicates) a year earlier. I imagine that by the time that reaches 100%, the sun will already have swallowed the earth.

Comment: @Erik https://xkcd.com/1822/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people already expressed thoughts like these in the comments, but I'll add a bit to the idea.

You are right that as time goes on, we have more questions to pull from, so the new questions posted are more and more likely to be duplicates. However, there will always be unique questions to be formed.

One of the types of unique questions are those pertaining to new technology. New languages or new packages or updates to whatever will be the source of many questions in the future that cannot be closed as a duplicate of anything existing previously because the content didn't exist before.

Another type are the debugging questions. Well asked debugging questions can be good questions if the code has been properly debugged by the author yet he or she is still stuck, and the code is streamlined and a more descriptive title than "My for loop is not working" is crafted above the question. These kinds of things will be different from other questions, and can still be on topic for Stack Overflow. And if they are well named, the solutions become searchable such that people with similar issues will be able to find their solution in someone else's debugging question.

We can also hope that with time as the general public gets used to Stack Overflow's existence that people will stop treating it as a personal help forum and realize the power it has in its existing content. Ideally, people will get used to expecting duplicates to exist already and in time will naturally search for their answer thoroughly first, thus leading to fewer duplicate questions being posted. I don't expect this to happen any time soon, but maybe in a decade or two when search engines become good enough to spoon-feed the right search results to people so that they don't have to try more than 2 or 3 searches to find their answer, people will become more willing to search for their answer, as they'll realize they can find and have their answer quicker searching for it than typing out their question.

In the mean time, the best thing we can do is to keep closing duplicates as they appear. This will help establish the idea that people can find almost any answer to their programming questions here by searching for their answer instead of asking something that has already been answered before.